# Populate a CheckBoxList from database table in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, checkboxlist

I am using vb.net to code and sqlserver 2008 as backend.
I have a checkboxlist that needs to be filled up with data from the database.
The data in the field is comma delimited (Blue, Red, Orange...)
How do i populate my checkbox with this data from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ddl.DataSource = data.split(',')
ddl.DataBind()
```